# Is fakephp hotplug-unplug driver in Linux is same as device disabe/enable feature in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I came across this article 
https://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/messing-around-with-linux-pci-hotplug/
which is a FAKE hotplug-unplug feature in windows. The author describes that by writing 0/1 to power file the device is plugged/unplugged. 
On windows we can disable/enable device using device manager.

Is fakephp hotplug-unplug driver in Linux is same as device disabe/enable feature in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Fakephp driver, which is already removed from upstream since the PCI core starts to do the same if asked, does logical removal from the system. Keep in mind that power is still goes to the device, though you might change it through PCI configuration space.

Comment: How does PCI core do that?