# How to tell linux retrain and scan PCIe bus?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, pci-e

We have an embedded board that has an iMX8M-Plus Processor and Linux v5.4.161. This board has one PCIe bus and that one is connected to an FPGA. When we power up the board, the FPGA is not yet configured, so it acts as if it was not on the PCIe bus.

Once the Linux is fully booted, we configure the FPGA and only after that it starts acting as a PCIe endpoint (device).

At this point, when I run `lspci` -> it returns nothing.
When I first execute `echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414024/how-can-the-linux-kernel-be-forced-to-enumerate-the-pci-e-bus?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334870/how-to-do-a-true-rescan-of-pcie-bus?rq=1) and then `lspci`, I still get nothing.

But if I reboot the linux without reseting the FPGA, it starts being visible in the `lspci` list. Rebooting the linux is not an option for us. Somehow I need to tell the linux that whatever it's doing at the boot time, please do it again at runtime. But I couldn't find a solution for this so far.

According to the Texas Instrument support forum, they said if the PCIe link is not trained at the boot time, `rescan` command never works.

At the boot time, while linux loads a pci driver, it tries to establish a PCIe link, I can see that with an oscilloscope, PERST pin is asserted and PCIE_CLK generated for a while and then stops if it can not detect any device. But the `rescan` command never does that.

Also in the system there is no pcie device to execute`echo 1 > $pcidevice/remove` in order to make `rescan` functional. Or there is no device or bus to set power off and on back like `echo 0 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/.../power`

I also learned that there was a method in old linux times (v2.6) called adding a Fake PCIe Device which physically doesn't exist to solve this problem. For that I took the `fakephp.c` driver from an old linux repo and ported it to ours. After solving a couple of deprecated function problems, it is compiled for Linux Kernel v5.4. `modprobe fakephp` worked and driver loaded but somehow I didn't get this fake device in my device list. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241277/is-fakephp-hotplug-unplug-driver-in-linux-is-same-as-device-disabe-enable-featur) it is mentioned that the fakephp driver was removed from mainstream linux since PCI core has similar functionality, but he never mentioned how.

Short of the story is that, I am stuck here, I need my FPGA to be visible in the `lspci` list without restarting the linux.

Comment: For hot-plug NVMe that I worked on the firmware must leave room in its device table.  Devices can't be moved once they are active.

Comment: Just a guess: Try your idea of `echo 1 > $pcidevice/remove` with pcidevice = the root port. Then set rescan.

Comment: @prl when the pcie link is not trained at the boot time, later on there is no device or root port defined in the sys folder to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend configuring the FPGA in u-boot to get away from these kinds of problems. Connect up SPI pins to FPGA's config pins & run it in Slave configuration mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try at the Linux prompt:

```
sudo echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have to do anything with programming.